# What can explain a deadlock only occuring with virtual threads?

Tags: concurrency, deadlock, java-21, virtual-threads

I am encountering a deadlock when using an executor based on virtual threads. The issue arises when I am using 50 threads but not at 20. The issue does not shows up when I am not using virtual threads.

I am looking for insights and recommendations on troubleshooting and resolving the deadlock problem unique to virtual threads, especially considering the absence of this issue when virtual threads are not in use.

```
private static final ExecutorService taskExecutor =0 Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CONCURRENT_WORKERS);
```

vs

```
private static final ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CONCURRENT_WORKERS, Thread.ofVirtual().factory());
```

The executor service is wrapped in a CompletionService.

```
private static final CompletionService<Data> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(taskExecutor)
```

The main thread seems to wait indefinitely on the first call `completionService.take()`.

Here is the relevant snippet of the code.

```
        for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < TASK_COUNT; taskIndex++) {
            completionService.submit(this::doTask);
        }
        log.info("Submitted all {} tasks to the executor, waiting.", TASK_COUNT);
        try {
            for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < TASK_COUNT; taskIndex++) {
                Future<Data> future = completionService.take();
                try {
                    var data = future.get();
                    storeData(data);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    log.warn("Error executing task", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

What could be the cause of the issue?

EDIT: this seems to be caused by an HTTP connection pool issue. I am using httpclient-4.5.14.

Internally this client use `synchronized` which according to my understanding is an issue for Virtual Threads as it pins the platform thread. I don't know if it can be the cause of the deadlock as I can't seen any error, neither weird stuff in the thread dump.

[image]

Trials: I tried to use the -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=full to check for pinned thread but no luck until now.

Comment: The code which performs the tasks is doing HTTP calls to a remote service using the httpclient-4.5.14 from Apache. I can't provide the full code unfortunately.

Any general advise on how to diagnose could be a good starting point.

Comment: Once you see the deadlock, you could use `jcmd <pid> Thread.dump_to_file -format=json dump.txt` to dump all the stack trances of the virtual threads, to see where they are getting stuck. You could also try `jstack <pid>`, but that only shows the platform threads

Comment: The implications of a `synchronized` block executed in a virtual thread are not worse than  executing the same `synchronized` block in a platform thread of a limited pool. You may encounter the same starvation issue. If the number of threads was sufficient when using platform threads, it should be sufficient with virtual threads too. It defeats the entire purpose of virtual threads, to maintain a fixed pool of them, though.

Comment: I think you're making a wrong assumption; that just because you only observe this when using virtual threads, that somehow it is connected to virtual threads.  Deadlocks are usually very timing sensitive; it may merely be that the differences in context switch behavior or scheduling create new interleavings that are uncommon with platform threads.  Virtual threads are threads; they only differ in where their stacks live, and who controls their scheduling (the Java runtime vs the OS.)  So this is likely just a plain vanilla deadlock.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with apache httpclient5. It’s a simple app with an endpoint that invokes another endpoint and sends back a response. When i turn on virtual threads (it’s just a flag in Spring boot 3.2.0), the app hangs completely with 300 concurrent requests. With virtual threads flag turned off, it just works fine.

Comment: @Haresh can you app handle 300 concurrent requests when you don’t use virtual threads?

Comment: It’s a sample app that I wrote to test virtual threads. It has a web endpoint that invokes another endpoint and returns a “Hello World”. 300 concurrent threads without using virtual threads, yes, quite easily.

Comment: @Haresh do you have the same problem with [the built-in http client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html)?

Comment: I tried the built in Http client and OkHttp client as well. Couldn’t get it running with either of them.

Comment: @Haresh, Abaddon, are you guys sure you are experiencing _deadlock_, not _hanging_? I was able to reproduce from the pattern the ticket describes a _hanging_, a situation very close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678836/executioncompletionservice-hangs-when-used-with-project-loom, but not a _deadlock_.  If your case is indeed a deadlock, could you provide stack traces Jorn Vernee suggested above? At least two threads (physical/carrier is OK) and two resources, IMHO, should be involved in a deadlock, and this information is critical in order to address the issue.