# ExecutionCompletionService hangs when used with Project loom

Tags: java, multithreading, java-21, project-loom

I am trying to use Project Loom to enable invoking a REST server in parallel. In the code snippet below, when I use virtual threads the executorService hangs, but I do not see the same behavior with traditional system threads. I have around 50000 API calls to be made, and are processed in chunks with size of 500.

After getting around 490+ responses using take() method, ExecutorService gets stuck/hangs (but with lower chunk size, it doesn't hang).

What could be the reason and why it's failing?

```
public List<ApiResponseWrapper> sendRequestToApi(List<ApiRequest> apiRequests) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ThreadFactory factory = Thread.ofVirtual().factory();
    List<ApiResponseWrapper> apiResponseWrappers = new ArrayList<>();
    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7, factory);
    final CompletionService<ApiEntityResponseWrapper> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(pool);
    List<RestTemplateClient> webClientCallables = apiRequests.stream().map(ApiRequest -> new RestTemplateClient(ApiRequest,restTemplate)).toList();
    webClientCallables.forEach(service::submit);
    pool.shutdown();
    int i = 0;
    try{
        for(RestTemplateClient webClient : webClientCallables){
            ApiResponseWrapper apiEntityResponseWrapper = service.take().get();
            apiResponseWrappers.add(apiEntityResponseWrapper);
            log.info("The size in webclient callables are reduced by {}", webClientCallables.size()-i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TibcoClientException ee){
        log.error("An exception occurred while processing requests towards Tibco ", ee.getCause());
        throw ee;
    }
    return apiResponseWrappers;
}
```

Comment: What does thread stack trace dump show?

Comment: Side note: creating a fixed thread pool of virtual threads defeats the purpose of virtual threads. You should [create a new virtual thread for every task](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()). Further, note the existence of [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)). There is no need for a `CompletionService` in the shown scenario.

Comment: @Holger, I would _guess_ that the purpose of the fixed thread pool is to limit the number of open network connections. The choice of platform threads vs. virtual threads for some given number of workers sounds like a secondary question.

Comment: @SolomonSlow then, it’s the wrong tool for the job. While thread pools had the side effect of limiting resource consumption they were not intended for that. With virtual threads, developers should use, e.g. semaphores to limit the access (when the API of the particular resource doesn’t provide configuration options in the first place). In short [Don't Pool Virtual Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-4A63E9EA-B16A-4633-87D8-C3DC08A3277C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments provided by @Holger is indeed correct and well supported. Summarizing the approach I took based on his/her comments.

1. Did away with CompletionService for invokeAll.
2. Used system threads instead of virtual.
3. Introduced Semaphores as it is more aligned to what I intend to achieve.